# how to show JSON result data in UITextView in objective c

Tags: objective-c, json

Please consider this code:

```
NSString *jsonreturn = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[ NSURL URLWithString:url ]]; // Pulls the URL
    NSLog(@"jsonreturn#########=%@",jsonreturn); // Look at the console and you can see what the restults are
    NSData *jsonData = [jsonreturn dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF32BigEndianStringEncoding];
    CJSONDeserializer *theDeserializer = [CJSONDeserializer deserializer];
    theDeserializer.nullObject = NULL;
    NSError *error = nil;        

    NSDictionary *dictt = [[CJSONDeserializer deserializer] deserializeAsDictionary:jsonData error:&error];
    NSLog(@"###dict=%@", dictt);
    if (dictt) {
        rowsForQuestion = [[dictt objectForKey:@"faqdetails"] retain];// NSArray rowsForQuestion
    }
    [jsonreturn release];
```

// I have got this data is in console NOW I WANT TO PRINT IT UITextView but HOW I can do it

```
  faqdetails =     (
                {
            faqAns = "Yes, Jack Kalis is the best crickter";
            faqQues = "who is the best cricketer in present year?";
        }
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question isn't particularly clear regarding what you want to show where, but dropped text into a UITextView couldn't be easier.

```
[yourTextView setText: [[rowsForQuestion objectAtIndex: 0] objectForKey: @"faqQues"]];
```

The above code grabs the first dict from `rowsForQuestion`, and puts its value for `@"faqQues"` into a UITextView.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a UITextView instance called `myTextView`, made either programatically or through IB, try this:

```
[myTextView setText:faqdetails];
```