# How to put JSON element into UITextView?

Tags: mysql, objective-c, json, uitextview

I have a MySQL database and a PHP script that work perfectly. However, I was wondering how I could get this data from JSON format to a UITextView. I also have a table being populated with 2 other JSON elements. Thanks!

TableInfo.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface TableInfo : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *Title;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *SubTitle;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *Description;

@end
```

HomeModel.h

```
 #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@protocol HomeModelProtocol <NSObject>

- (void)itemsDownloaded:(NSArray *)items;

@end

@interface HomeModel : NSObject <NSURLConnectionDataDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, weak) id<HomeModelProtocol> delegate;

- (void)downloadItems;

@end
```

HomeModel.m

```
#import "HomeModel.h"
#import "TableInfo.h"

@interface HomeModel()
{
    NSMutableData *_downloadedData;
}
@end

@implementation HomeModel

- (void)downloadItems
{
    // Download the json file
    NSURL *jsonFileUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://gandouhaiti.ueuo.com/service.php"];
    NSLog(@"Donwload the JSON file");

    // Create the request
    NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:jsonFileUrl];
    NSLog(@"Create the request");

    // Create the NSURLConnection
    [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:urlRequest delegate:self];
    NSLog(@"Create the NSURLConnection");
}

#pragma mark NSURLConnectionDataProtocol Methods

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{
    NSLog(@"Inititalize the data object");

    // Initialize the data object
    _downloadedData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
    // Append the newly downloaded data
    [_downloadedData appendData:data];
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    // Create an array to store the locations
    NSMutableArray *_locations = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    // Parse the JSON that came in
    NSError *error;
    NSArray *jsonArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:_downloadedData options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:&error];

    // Loop through Json objects, create question objects and add them to our questions array
    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.count; i++)
    {
        NSDictionary *jsonElement = jsonArray[i];

        // Create a new location object and set its props to JsonElement properties
        TableInfo *newdata = [[TableInfo alloc] init];
        newdata.Title = jsonElement[@"Title"];
        newdata.SubTitle = jsonElement[@"SubTitle"];
        newdata.description = jsonElement[@"Description"];

       // Add this question to the locations array
        [_locations addObject:newdata];
    }

    // Ready to notify delegate that data is ready and pass back items
    if (self.delegate)
    {
        [self.delegate itemsDownloaded:_locations];
    }
}

@end
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to show JSON result data in UITextView in objective c](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8358107/how-to-show-json-result-data-in-uitextview-in-objective-c)

Comment: I tried using both methods but neither worked.

Comment: Add an `NSLog( @"%@", jsonArray );` after the `NSJSONSerialization` line and post the results here. Also take a look at this post and see if it helps [cant-get-head-around-parsing-nested-json](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24072891/cant-get-head-around-parsing-nested-json)

Comment: When I add `NSLog( @"%@", jsonArray );`, I get the following. `(
        {
        Description = "Description Test";
        SubTitle = "SubTitle Test";
        Title = "Title Test";
    }
)` That is exactly what my JSON is. @user3386109

Comment: I see, so the problem is not in parsing the JSON, it's putting the results into a UITextView.  To do that, use NSString's `stringWithFormat` method to create a string containing the JSON information. You can use `\n` to force line breaks in the text. Then use the `.text` property of the UITextView to display the string in the text view.

Comment: Excuse my n00bish but I would need to import the HomeModel.h into the view controller (right?) and then how would I use NSString `stringWithFormat` to pull the JSON from the HomeModel into readable text? @user3386109

Comment: Yes, you would need to import HomeModel.h in the view controller. The view controller needs to implement the `HomeModelProtocol` and must set itself as the `delegate` for the HomeModel object.  The view controller will then receive an `NSArray` of `TableInfo` objects in the `itemsDownloaded` method.

Answer (score 0):

If you wan to display the JSON in UITextView in storyboard, kindly try the following:

```
@implementation ViewController

NSString * JSON;
-(void) viewDidLoad
{
   JSON = //get data from remote;
   NSString *stringForTextView = @"";
   NSData *data =  [JSON dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
   NSArray *array = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:nil];
   if([array count] >0)
   {
      for(NSDictionary *d in array)
      {
      stringForTextView = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Title:%@\nSubTitle:%@\nDescription:%@\n", [d valueForKey:@"Title"], [d valueForKey:@"SubTitle"], [d valueForKey:@"Description"]];
      }
   }
   _textView.text = stringForTextView;

}
@end
```